# How to use CRSF and XSS protection in Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

what is the best practice with some examples for using CRSF and XSS protections on Strapi?

I have several forms in HTML and also a mobile App that are calling APIs in Strapi and I am looking for a way to prevent the CRSF and XSS issues.

Also if I am generating the CSRF token with expressJS, can these be validated from the Strapi when submitting the data?

Thanks a lot

Georgios

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with srapi.io but it seems that you are searching for [policies](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/concepts/concepts.html#policies)

> Policies are functions which have the ability to execute specific logic on each request before it reaches the controller's action. They are mostly used for securing business logic easily. Each route of the project can be associated to an array of policies. For example, you can create a policy named isAdmin, which obviously checks that the request is sent by an admin user, and use it for critical routes.
>   https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/concepts/concepts.html#policies